# Django - different html/css/js code for each page

Tags: django

I have created a book application - each book contains several sections and each section contains several sub-sections.

The app works fine and each sub-section "shows" its content on the right page etc..
Problem is that I want that each sub-section will have a different html/css/js code & effects.

Here is some of the URLS.PY code:

```
 url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
 (r'^$', direct_to_template, {'template': 'index.html'}),
 (r'^book/$','book.views.BookAll'),
 (r'^book/$','book.views.BookAll'),

 (r'^book/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$','book.views.Ssection_specific'),
 (r'^book/info/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$','book.views.Ssection_details'),
```

)

Some of the views.py code:

```
def Ssection_specific(request, slug): #display according to specified section object.
    try:
            section = Section.objects.get(slug=slug)
    except Section.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404        
    ssection = SSection.objects.filter(section = section).order_by('subject')
context = {'ssection' : ssection,'section' : section}
    return render_to_response('section_display.html', context, context_instance = RequestContext(request))# creates

def Ssection_details(request, slug):
    try:
            ssection = SSection.objects.get(slug = slug)
    except SSection.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404
    context = {'ssection' : ssection}
    return render_to_response('info/ssection_disp.html', context, context_in)
```

As you can see, each sub section's page is determined by the slug.
Of course that each one of them will have the SAME template and that is my problem.
I want to make different css/js effects for each page.

Comment: 'info/ssection_disp.html' and 'section_display.html' are different pages rigth? If they are you don't have to use same css/js for the pages. You can use different css/js in different pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create base.html

**base.html**

```
<html>
   <head>
       <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>

       {% block css %}{% endblock %}
       {% block js %}{% endblock %}
   </head>

   <body>
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
   </body>
</html>
```

**page1.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}{{block.super}}"title here"{% endblock %}

{% block css %}{{block.super}}
     "css here"
{% endblock %}

{% block js %}{{block.super}}
     "js here"
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
     content here
{% endblock %}
```

Follow this pattern in other pages and you can now use different css/js as you want